# Mysql error 1451 but no line with referenced id can be found

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, cascade, mysql-error-1451

I need to delete a row from A table. I get a 1451 error which means a constraint failed. But when i try to find this relation, nothing comes up.

```
mysql> delete from A where id=961;
ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key 
    constraint fails (`xxx`.`B`, CONSTRAINT `FK_D273C62CBE4E457A` FOREIGN KEY 
    (`agencementDimension_id`) REFERENCES `A` (`id`))
mysql> select * from B where agencementDimension_id=961;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Constraints had been generated by Doctrine + Symfony 2. I have added "cascade delete" and updated schema but nothing changed "The database schema is in sync with the mapping files".

Comment: try to delete child rows which linked up to id = 961

Comment: Next time if u make relationship and if you have this type requirement use ON DELETE CASCADE when creating constraint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Symfony 2 and Doctrine 2, I added ON DELETE CASCADE thanks to the JoinColumn onDelete property to the constraint :

```
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="agencementDimension_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
```

That changed the MySQL error message to :

```
mysql> delete from A where id=961;
ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: 
a foreign key constraint fails (`xxx`.`C`, CONSTRAINT `FK_BF92805FD55A3663` 
FOREIGN (`agencementVersionDimension_id`) REFERENCES `B` (`id`))
```

I had a second relation between B and C. I don't know why MySQL didn't tell me that from the start. Anyway, i have been able to delete the lines from C, which allowed me to delete lines from A !

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this problem ADD `ON DELETE CASCADE` in your contraint

here a post showing how to do it in symfony doctrine

[On delete cascade with doctrine2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328535/on-delete-cascade-with-doctrine2)

Comment: I'm using Symfony + doctrine to generate schema and request, I d'ont want to mess with auto-generated constraints :/

Comment: By adding "onDelete=CASCADE", mysql error message changed and i noticed i had a third table, a child of the child ! That was the problem, i added "onDelete=CASCADE" on the second relation too and it did the trick ! Thanks ! Do I need to create a message with the solution and mark it as resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

This error is saying that you have table A with field name 'id' and which is used somewhere as reference for field "agencementDimension_id" so you can't delete this record

you have to either delete all child rows in order to delete this record OR you can auto delete by setting `ON DELETE CASCADE` property on foreign key constrain

Comment: If you look at my second request, i didn't find any child. That's what makes me suspicious .

Comment: Check and follow accepted answer provided here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257004/doctrine2-symfony2-cascading-remove-integrity-constraint-violation-1451
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487042/symfony2-doctrinefixturesbundle-cant-load-fixtures-due-to-foreign-key-constra

I think any of these should solve your problem